# Where would I go to learn to make a really, really secure system that DOES expose external services (out of a standard Windows or Linux OS)

Tags: linux, windows, security

Where would I go to learn to set up a really, really secure system that DOES expose external services (out of a standard Windows or Linux OS). Note that I am not looking for a favorite choice between Linux and Windows, as the choice is not likely to be mine to make. However the level of security needs to be military grade.

Comment: Military grade == NOT exposing services to the internet.  They use secure communication lines. ;-)

Comment: The choice of OS should be almost irrelevant because the real protection needs to be applied well before the server anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Milatary Grade does does include exposing services. There are NSA offices all over the country and they have got to move a lot of data around somehow. I suppose I am assuming the only true "secured line" is a physical line with no external connections. Anything else and there must be software on both ends of that line that attempt to discern whether incoming data is authorized and thus it is exposing a "service".

Comment: 'Military Grade' is effectively a worthless term here.

Comment: No its not a worthless term. It means something that would be safe against a very powerful, very determined adversary (like a rival country). Its just a shorter way of saying it.

Comment: Networks that have secret clearance data on it are not connected to the Internet in any way that can access the Internet or accessed from the Internet.  They may have VPN tunnels between offices connecting the secured networks together but at no time would that sort of network be allowed to route any data to or from any untrusted network.

Comment: "Military Grade" might not be a worthless term, but it's certainly ambiguous. Military grade in the ability to withstand a nuclear event, the ability to withstand the hacking attempts of rogue governments, whose military? Etc., etc.

Comment: You might be more in luck with this question over at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/stig/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a good place to start.  However, read my comment above.
Also start with a secured OS and open things up as needed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach the security/services open to internet combination would be through some VM technology like CentOS/Xen (or MS HyperV or VMWare or KVM or plane old VirtualBox). Each VM can have a unique IP which could be put in your router's DMZ. You can have have VM backups and mirrors for redundancies. If you went the Xen route I suppose [Xen Wiki](http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/) is where you would want to start.